# jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut transition is not visible (since updated Firefox to 34)

Tags: jquery, css, fadein, opacity, fadeout

I have 3 slides with basic fadeIn/fadeOut effect. So when first slide fadeOut effect is complete, the next slide fadeIn and so on.

The problem is that the transition (which is CSS opacity from 1 to 0) is not visible.

This started happening when I updated Firefox to v.34

Any ideas?

FIX: after removing `float: left` from each slide, transition started to be visible.

Comment: Show us the code that has this issue.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP edited in a fix to their question.

Comment: @Mooseman: The question isn't invalid because OP 'fixed' it in his question. He should edit it out and make an answer of it.

Answer (score 0):

Add clearfix classes to your css. If already there then add .clearfix class to floated elements parent tag. Floated elements are not counted as part when parents demention calculated.

Comment: yeah, the problem had something to do with floats... since I removed floating from each slide, the transition is visible already.

Answer (score 0):

FIX: after removing float: left from each slide, transition started to be visible.